# Escaping a colon(:) in CakePHP urls

Tags: cakephp

I've got a simple cakePHP action that looks up a post that somebody has made by it's title, as passed through the url parameters. Recently, a post was put in that contained a colon (`:`) in the title, which cake interpreted as a named parameter.

Although it wouldn't be too hard to construct the url with

```
str_replace(':', 'BANANA!_replace_colons, YAY safenow', $name)
```

I'm curious if there's a standard, or more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could always urlencode the title if you want to pass it in the url.

if the post title is "foo:bar" instead of

```
/post/foo:bar
```

you should have

```
/post/foo%3Abar
```

because later you might have a post title that contains a slash `/` and you'll have to add another str_replace... or maybe there will be characters with accents.

In my case I always have a second field on the table called "title_url" which is the [Slug](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html#Inflector::slug) of the title, and I use this `title_url` in the urls. So in my example, the url would be something like

```
/post/foo_bar
```

which is a little more human-readable than the urlencode.

However, there is an option on the router called ["greedy star" (`/*`) and the "trailing star" (`/**`)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#connecting-routes). They will help you capture the parameter even if they contain special characters

Hope this helps

Comment: CakePHP seems to still read %3A as a colon when called in Router::parse()
I tried Router::url(array('controller' => 'tests', 'action' => 'test', 'A:A', 'C:ause' => 'E:ffect')) to see the results
tests/test/A%3AA/C:ause:E%3Affect

Comment: Interesting, if I pass the url with %3A into Router::parse() it reads it properly, placing it in the passed/numbered parameters. But if I submit it in the url bar, it recognizes the %3A as a colon and splits it into named parameters.

Comment: encode the value twice: `: -> %3a -> %253a`. Undo the second encode within the action receiving the value.

Comment: that's why I use the slug n_n urlencode always gives me a headache

Answer (score 1):

I just went with array('action' => 'view', 'name' => $name);
Cake seems to be able to handle everything past the first colon just fine.